# How i remove another class from my header section for inner page

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I make a project in wordpress. I used a conman class for header section called "header" but only for home page i used another class "home-header with header". i.e.

```
<header class="header home-header">
<div class="container">
<div class="logo"><a href="index.html"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/logo.png" alt=""></a></div>
<div class="connect">
  <label><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/small-phone-icon.png" alt="">(540) 455-5057</label>
  <label><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/small-mail-icon.png" alt=""><a href="mailto:info@lifesourcecounseling.com">info@lifesourcecounseling.com</a></label>
</div>
<nav>
  <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu', 'menu_id' => 'primary-menu' ) ); ?>
</nav>
```

My question is how i remove home-header class from inner pages the home-header class not for inner pages?

class header is default for the site.

Please help my....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on wordpress, usualy on the first page , the `.body` has class `.home` or something specific for the first page

if you already gave `<header>` the class `home-header` in the html

use this **[jsfiddle 1](https://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/vs3z5Lbr/2/)**

```
if (!$("body").hasClass("home")) {
    $("header").removeClass("home-header")
}
```

the `!` means `not` so you read it like  *if header has**NOT**class home*

if you want to give the `header` classes only from JQ .

use this : **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/vs3z5Lbr/1/)**

```
if ($("body").hasClass("home")) {
    $("header").addClass("home-header")
}else{
    $("header").addClass("header")
}
```

or if your `<header>` has class `header` and you want to add a class only for first page. use the code below :

```
$("body.home header").addClass("home-header")
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please add below php code it works.

```
<header class="header<?php echo ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) ? ' home-header' : ''; ?>">
<div class="container">
<div class="logo"><a href="index.html"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/logo.png" alt=""></a></div>
<div class="connect">
  <label><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/small-phone-icon.png" alt="">(540) 455-5057</label>
  <label><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/small-mail-icon.png" alt=""><a href="mailto:info@lifesourcecounseling.com">info@lifesourcecounseling.com</a></label>
</div>
<nav>
  <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu', 'menu_id' => 'primary-menu' ) ); ?>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use WordPress function 'is_front_page()'. If yes then apply that class or else no. It is recommended not to use JS for those cases. It can increase page weight.

Answer (score 0):

Solution gotit:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
if ($("body").hasClass("home")) {
$("header").addClass("home-header")
}else{
$("header").removeClass("home-header")
}
});
```